# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

Собственно поставил(опубликовал) я асп сервер на iis. Вроде все заработало, но если хочу зайти на него не через localhost - пишет ошибку 400. На другом устройстве сервер видится, но также 400 ошибка.

Что нужно сделать чтобы переместить сервер с localhost на ip? В основном все что я находил были старые способы в которых снимали галочку в настройках в пункте связанном с override URL. В нынешних настройках я такого не нашел.

Наверняка проблема в самом сервере и я не знаю что менять. Уже все потыкал вроде, только новых ошибок с соединением с IIS нахватался. Если нужно, то вот код launchSettings:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49461",
      "sslPort": 44395
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Если потребуется еще код - могу дополнить.

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит как "что нужно сделать, чтобы переместить карандаш со стола на поверхность?". У вас хостинг? Какой? В курсе ли вы, как работает HTTP и TCP/IP? А про что такое веб-сервер, читали? IIS/Apache/Nginx - все работают в целом по одному и тому же принципу. Кажется, вам не хватает фундаментальных знаний. 400 Bad Request - это "плохой запрос", то есть сервер по этому адресу и пути ожидает от вас не то, что вы ему отправили. Это говорит о том, что проблема может быть не только в конфигурации сервера, а еще у вас в коде. Почему вы решили, что она в конфигурации?

Comment: Начните с простого, попробуйте настроить IIS чтоб он отдавал простую статичную страничку по ip адресу вашего компа, а не через localhost. А затем уже экспериментируйте с asp.net.

Comment: Я хочу внутри локальной сети использовать, для этого, как я понимаю, не нужен хостинг. Почему решил что в конфигурации - в IIS все работает у меня, я создавал без asp и мог запускать с другого устройства, а вот когда подключил asp начало выдавать вот это. Поэтому я и подумал, что проблема с созданным кодом или конфигурацией и нужно что-то изменить. Да и в основном в статьях что я читал люди либо конфигурацию меняли(что вызывало у меня ошибки подключения к iis), либо убирали галку из override url.

Comment: Код просто шаблонный созданный самой VS, я его вообще не трогал. Я хотел сначала выпустить его в локальную сеть, а потом уже использовать. Может быть мне для этого использовать обычный http (не https), при создании можно выбрать http. Но галка стояла по умолчанию на https, поэтому я не стал ее трогать

Comment: Походу только что что-то сломал и теперь даже с localhost не хочет заходить. Ладно буду что-нибудь думать

Answer (score 2):

Решилось. Все дело, как я понял, было в том, что у меня, как оказалось, не был установлен .NET Core Windows Server Hosting. После все уже запустилось как на моем, так и на других устройствах локальной сети по ссылке http://192.168.0.106:59869/ . Невнимательно прочитал и мучался с этим пару часов.

Comment: А как ты понял, что такая ссылка нужна?

Answer (score 1):

я почитал вот эту статью:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core

и там главная суть:
Exposing IIS Express to the Network
If you want to use IIS Express and allow external access, you need to explicitly change the bindings in the solution applicationhost.config file which can be found in .vs\config. Change the bindingInformation to:
changing the *:26448:localhost to *:26448:* where 26448 is the IIS Express port.

Я вместо этого добавил у себя пару строк и получилось вот так:

```
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62731:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44377:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44377:win10-hann" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:62731:win10-hann" />
    </bindings>
```

Короче ниже добавил копии локалхостов с dns именем win10-hann. После этого из локалки я смог запрашивать Kestrel таким образом:

https://win10-hann:44377/index.html